# Expression for an abrupt change in height

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, geography

Is there an expression for an abrupt change in height? I’m looking for a word for the edge of the change, like in the German word *Geländekante*.

Comment: Perhaps "discontinuity" would work for you?

Comment: Your question is not very specific and also somewhat self contradictory. Is it the change in height you're looking for or the edge? Also, did you attempt to look for a translation of 'Geländekante'? What is the definition (in English) of that word? That might help us better here since this isn't German-English-translation.SE.

Comment: If you are referring to a human, I believe *decapitation* is the usual term.

Comment: @Eric: There's always the possibility of ***double pedectomy*** (amputation of both feet) if you want a less drastic way of reducing height. Or just ***defenestration*** if all you want to do is (rapidly) lower the elevation of the entire intact body (by throwing it out of the window! :)

Comment: @Mitch: I was going to ask the same thing, but instead I looked for a translation myself. Among the example usages there, I noted *horizontalen Förderflusses ist es zu verdanken, dass dazu keine **Geländekante** oder **Auffahrrampe** im Vergleich zu klassischen Vorbrechanlagen* translated as *Thanks to the unique technology of the horizontal flow neither a **bench edge,** nor a **loading ramp** is required for the feeding in comparison*. From which I assume the German word covers a wide range of contexts, not just enormous geological features. But an accurate "translation" would be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **cliff** or **precipice** is at the boundary to an abrupt change in altitude.

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+cliff&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en):

> cliff
>
> a steep rock face, especially at the edge of the sea.
>
> synonyms: precipice, rock face, crag, bluff, ridge, escarpment, scar,

related: shelf

Comment: Ok, even if the change is not so dramatic (without bare rock)?

Comment: @parallax: *bluff* may be less steep, no rocks necessary

Comment: And does the english language differ between the cliff, bluff, ... and the "fictive line" at which the change starts? I mean the edge where the terrain begins to fall. Something like terrain ridge?

Comment: @parallax: the edge is the edge, could also be *brink, threshold, lip, rim*

Comment: Yes, I think brink is the word I'm looking for

Comment: @parallax Sounds like you just want *edge*.

Comment: Yes only the edge in the context of terrain. I think brink, as chillin wrote, describes the situation quite good.

Answer (score 6):

I don't speak German, but looking at [this page](http://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/gel%C3%A4ndekante.html) it seems to me ***Geländekante*** can apply to *any* abrupt change in "level".

Those examples range from "height discontinuities" of hundreds/thousands of feet (cliffs, [Ayers Rock](https://deanoworldtravels.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/uluru-height-comparison-2.jpg)) to mere inches (kerb between road and pavement, small mismatch in a loading bay area). So I think the short answer is there is no equivalent "generic" word or common expression for this in English.

> 1: At the "geological" level there are lots of terms (***cliff, escarpment, bluff,*** etc.), with the same or overlapping meanings.
>
> 2: Somewhere in the middle - usually from the "above" perspective, with emphasis on the danger of falling over the edge - are terms like ***precipice, drop***.
>
> 3: At smaller scales (the most likely context where you'd need a more general-purpose term) the best bet is probably ***step*** *(Mind the step = Don't trip over the upcoming small change in level)*.

Comment: Given those examples, maybe prominence or protuberance fit?

Comment: @Mark: Not so sure about *prominence*, but *protuberance* would certainly work in some contexts (though it's more "bit sticking up" rather than "change of level").

Comment: I was thinking prominence not as the state of being prominent, but rather this definition: *a thing that projects from something, especially a projecting feature of the landscape or a protuberance on a part of the body.*

Answer (score 3):

If you are specifically referring to a change in height of a person (a human) - then we call that a "spurt", or more specifically a "growth spurt" - when a child grows inches taller, almost overnight.

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of words for these things that vary in aspect, specificity, origin, and region. Sometimes they emphasize the vertical aspect; other times the line at the top or bottom. Some are for collections of these things; others for singular instances.

- cliff
- bluff
- breaks
- palisades
- scarp
- escarpment
- fault
- face
- ridge
- cuesta
- wall
- hogback
- pediment
- cleaver
- sérac
- kame
- buttress
- cornice
- rampart
- cirque
- headwall
- nunatuk
- defile
- quebrada
- huérfano
- rimland
- badlands
- yardang
- arête
- combs ridge
- banco
- postpile
- malpais
- louderback
- castle rock
- tsegi
- slab
- pali
- morro

Some of these terms are common and general; others rare and specific. There are many more.  Some are found in every dictionary; others only in specialty lexicons devoted to geography.  One of the latter can be found at the web site [Home Ground: Language for an American Landscape](http://test.ourhomeground.com).

Comment: I've never heard of several of those. But you missed out the only one I can think of for height changes that can be traversed in a single movement - ***step***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Be careful with *step*: it also means a comparatively level and treeless plain, which is often spelled *steppe*. That version is actually derived from Russian *степь* (*step’*).  A different sort of steps occur in the giant stairs of [the Grand Staircase–Escalate National Monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Staircase-Escalante_National_Monument) and storied—and storeyed—pages of [the Book Cliffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_Cliffs) of the Colorado Uplift, where the landscape looks truly like *eald enta geweorc* yet on a scale inconceivable in the British Isles.

Comment: I'd always spell it *steppe(s)* anyway - not that that would help resolve ambiguity in speech. But at the time I answered, *all* the existing answers were at the "geological feature" level, whereas it seems to me OP's German "target to match" has much broader application. In any real-world context where the step up/down is a matter of *inches*, there's no chance of ambiguity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It might just be *edge*; I’m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Scarp**, or **escarpment**.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarp):

1. Cliff, a significant vertical, or near vertical, rock exposure
2. Escarpment, a steep slope or long rock that occurs from erosion or faulting and separates two relatively level areas of differing elevations

Answer (score 0):

Some comments clarified that the context is terrain.

In this case, you could say *The road (or path, or ground, or whatever) **dropped off sharply** OR **rose sharply**.*  If you google these phrases, you'll see they're extremely common.

(Next time, could you provide the context in your question, please?)